# Old virtual keyboard on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, ipad, wkwebview

`WKWebView` shows old virtual keyboard on iPad Pro (simulator) not the new layout I'm used to on the iPad Pro.

I tried to use newer build targets since i couldn't find any settings within Interface Builder regarding keyboard layout. No clues in API of `WKWebView` and `UIView` either.

Basically I have no idea how to fix this.

here are some infos about my app and screenshots from the virtual keyboards to compare.

- Use current Xcode Version 9.1
- Apps Build Target is iOS 8
- App is Universal
- App has Storyboard for iPad
- Storyboard file opens in Xcode 9
- Storyboard file builds for iOS 8
- `WKWebView` is initialised and added via `addSubview()` in `viewDidLoad()`

Keyboard in my app:
[image]

Keyboard in message app:
[image]

Comment: Is it the simulator or real device?

Comment: @Sulthan both. (screenshots are obviously from simulator)